# Vertically align geom_label elements

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

#### Problem

I am trying to vertically align geom_label's on a line chart without visibly extending the x-axis. Is there a way I can make white space on the right of the chart so that the `ggrepel` function (below) has space to work?

I am trying to replicate the last chart on [this](https://www.karambelkar.info/2016/03/alternative-to-using-legends-in-ggplot2/) post by Karam Belkar (see bottom of post for code) except without the `facet_wrap` and using the `economic` example data set in `ggplot`.

When I use `expand_limits` get the error message:

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

But economics$date is of Date format!

#### Code that is not quiet there:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("ggthemes")
library("ggrepel")

df1 <- gather(economics, variable_name, observation, -date) %>% 
  rename(period = date) %>% 
  filter(variable_name %in% c("pce", "unemploy"))

p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = period, y = observation, colour = variable_name)) +
  geom_line() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(df1$period), max(df1$period))) +
#Alternative line to that above with undesirable result 
#coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(df1$period), max(df1$period) **+ 3000**)) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = subset(df1, period == max(period)),
    aes(label = variable_name),
    size = 3,
    nudge_x = 45,
    segment.color = 'grey80'
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_tableau() + 
  scale_fill_tableau() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  labs(x="", y="", title = "Economic Data") 


p + expand_limits(x = 700)
#the data set has 574 observations so I tried to 
#add another 126 to give space to the labels
```

The `ggrepel` [Usage Examples page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html) has some examples based on Orange Tree growth data under the heading of 'Line Plot'. That involves adding an `x` value in the `coord_cartesian` function to increase the x-axis. That gives room for the label behaviour I need but it means that the x-axis extends out past the year 2020 with no data above that part of the graph, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

It's necessary to provide the axis limits in date format, using `expand_limits(x=700)` throws this off, the following works below where it is incorporated in `scale_x_date`.  I used 1200 instead of 700 to create the attached graph.

```
p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = period, y = observation, colour = variable_name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = subset(df1, period == max(as.Date(period, "%Y-%m-%d"))),
    aes(label = variable_name),
    size = 3,
    nudge_x = 45,
    segment.color = 'grey80'
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_tableau() + 
  scale_fill_tableau() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  labs(x="", y="", title = "Economic Data") 
p + scale_x_date(limits = c(min(df1$period), max(df1$period) + 1200))
```

[image]

Comment: That's an improvement over what I had. I am wondering if it's possible to avoid having the extra space on the x-axis beneath the labels, and instead have just white space?

Comment: Do you mean removing the 2020 label and the associated gridline?

Comment: Yes, and that segment of the x-axis.